# Shovel cannot import 'task'

Tags: python

Here is my `shovel.py`

```
from shovel import task

@task
def hello():
    println "Hello World!"
```

However when I run it I get this:

```
$ shovel hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "shovel.py", line 1, in <module>
    from shovel import task
ImportError: cannot import name task
```

Why can't python find `task` in the `shovel` module?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your Python is looking for `task` from within your own `shovel.py` rather than the global `shovel` module. Fix this by moving `shovel.py` to a `shovel` directory.

```
mkdir shovel
mv shovel.py shovel
shovel hello
```